# yfinance returning incorrect prices

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

Ticker:  ITT

2021-12-06 23:53:21 , market price: 99.69 , previous close price: 95.76

2021-12-06 23:53:35 , market price: 99.69 , previous close price: 95.76

2021-12-06 23:53:51 , market price: 99.69 , previous close price: 95.76

2021-12-06 23:54:09 , market price: 95.76 , previous close price: 96.49

2021-12-06 23:54:27 , market price: 95.76 , previous close price: 96.49

= RESTART:

Ticker:  ITT

2021-12-07 00:22:04 , market price: 99.69 , previous close price: 95.76

2021-12-07 00:22:18 , market price: 99.69 , previous close price: 95.76

2021-12-07 00:22:31 , market price: 99.69 , previous close price: 95.76

```
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import time

symbol = 'ITT'
print ('Ticker: ', symbol)

count = 0
while count < 20:
    stock_info = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    try:
        market_price = stock_info.info['regularMarketPrice']
        previous_close_price = stock_info.info['regularMarketPreviousClose']
    except:
        print ('Ticker: ', symbol, ', Error getting prices')
    else:
        now = datetime.now()
        print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), ', market price:' , market_price, ', previous close price:', previous_close_price)
    count = count + 1
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is incorrect?

Comment: The correct market price is 99.69 but every now & then I get a price of 95.76.

Comment: The correct market price for ticker ITT is currently 99.69 but every now & then I get a price of 95.76. Earlier, during market hours, I ran thru about 150 funds using python calling yfinance and while most prices were correct I did notice a few that were incorrect. So I waited till after hours when the price should remain stable, 99.69, and I wrote the above program to run it every so many seconds to see if the price changes and it did. Hope that helps explain it.

Comment: I am not able to recreate the error. I am getting the market price as 99.69 and the previous close market price as 95.76, consistently.

Comment: Also I check the Yahoo Financial website when I get back 95.76 and the website shows 99.69.

Comment: You think it could be something locally ?

Comment: That is unlikely. Can you try getting other values from yfinance and checking if they give out correct values consistently?

Comment: running AAPL, 1st 5 times showed market price as 165.32 which is correct, next 15 times showed market price as 161.84 which is actually the previous close price.

Comment: Same issue with ABBV, 1st 11 times showed market price as 121.35 which is correct, next 9 times showed market price as 118.85 which is actually the previous close price.

Comment: Which version of yfinance are you using? I am using Version: 0.1.67 and everything works for me perfectly. Try upgrading/downgrading to Version: 0.1.67.

Comment: I am currently running Version: 0.1.67

Comment: I ran a Powerwash (reset) on my Chromebook and reloaded Python and yfinance. On 12/08 I retrieved prices using yfinance for about 150 tickers 5 times (about 750 calls) and all prices were correct except 1 (and that price was off by several days). On 12/09 I retrieved prices using yfinance for about 150 tickers 6 times (about 900 calls) and all prices were correct.

Comment: at least add a brief explanation of your issues

Comment: No issues, I was just following up on my earlier issue and now that I removed & reloaded everything appears to be working fine.